# Kohana URL not found

Tags: php, webserver, kohana

Hi i have a problem with my kohana code it's getting me the same error and i think there's a problem with the htaccess or bootstrap

It's installed on my root directory not as a subfolder.

```
Kohana_HTTP_Exception [ 404 ]: The requested URL / was not found on this server.

SYSPATH/classes/Kohana/Request/Client/Internal.php [ 79 ]

74          if ( ! class_exists($prefix.$controller))
75          {
76              throw HTTP_Exception::factory(404,
77                  'The requested URL :uri was not found on this server.',
78                  array(':uri' => $request->uri())
79              )->request($request);
80          }
81 
82          // Load the controller using reflection
83          $class = new ReflectionClass($prefix.$controller);
84 

    SYSPATH/classes/Kohana/Request/Client.php [ 114 ] » Kohana_Request_Client_Internal->execute_request(arguments)

    SYSPATH/classes/Kohana/Request.php [ 990 ] » Kohana_Request_Client->execute(arguments)

    DOCROOT/index.php [ 109 ] » Kohana_Request->execute()
```

Here's my htaccess code

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]

#-SetEnv KOHANA_ENV "production"
```

and in the bootstrap i have set the site_url to '/'

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem when I moved kohana from localhost to linux hosting.

Try to rename your controller files in capital letters. In bootstrap routes keep small letters.

It helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Please try and post much of the bootstrap.php file as possible. Chances are that you do not have a default root set.

Search within your file for a code block that looks like

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'default',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

The keyword being `Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')`

Where is your application hosted? Is it on www or within a subfolder in www?

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is the error that is thrown when you haven't [set up your environment to run for the first time to use clean urls](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/tutorials/clean-urls). Do this:

1. go into your `.htaccess` file and set the correct path for `RewriteBase`
   if your localhost path where `localhost/my/site`, your htaccess should be:

   `RewriteBase /localhost/my/site/`

   (make sure you rename the file so it is ONLY called `.htaccess` )
2. Go into your bootstrap.php file and make sure `Kohana::init` has:

   `'base_url'   =>  '/localhost/my/site/'` in its array.
3. Inside the `/application/classes/Controller/` directory, add your controller file name the file so that the first letter is uppercase (i.e. `Welcome.php`) and inside the controller, make sure your controller contents are written correctly.

   `/application/classes/Controller/Welcome.php`

That's a good start towards solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This exception was throwed because controller not found. By default, '/' URI means calling method `action_index()` of `Controller_Welcome`. See `bootstrap.php`, `Route::set('default', ...)`.

I think, there can be one of these reasons:

1. You have default route, and `application/classes/Controller/Welcome.php` was removed.
2. While upgrading Kohana version to v3.3, you havent replace `application` folder with new one. So, you have `application/classes/controller/welcome.php` instead of `application/classes/Controller/Welcome.php`.
3. You have changed default route with non-existing controller. Note that Kohana v3.3 has new [file/class naming conventions](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/upgrading#psr-0-support-fileclass-naming-conventions).